# How to add image and div using jquery in a dynamically added wrapped div?

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic

I have a div,say main div, and using jQuery, I am adding an image in wrapped div to the main div.That is done for multiple images I want to upload.I am done with that.

But now,I also need to add an a tag along with image and want to have one more wrapped div inside that. How do I achieve the same?

```
$("<img />", {
        "src": e.target.result,
        "class": "thumb-image "+imgCls[i]
}).appendTo(image_holder).wrapAll("<div class='uimg_holder'></div>");
```

This give me:

```
<div class="image_holder">
  <div class="uimg_holder">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="uimg_holder">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to have :

```
   <div class="image_holder">
      <div class="uimg_holder">
        <img src="..." />
        <a href=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="uimg_holder">
        <img src="..." />
        <a href=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using this with no success:

```
var nhtml="<a href='#'>Close</a>";
    $("<img />"+ nhtml , {
       "src": e.target.result,
        "class": "thumb-image "+imgCls[i]
    }).appendTo(image_holder).wrapAll("<div class='uimg_holder'></div>");
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to achieve it.

> the `.add()` method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those elements and the ones passed into the method.

```js
var image_holder = $('.image_holder')
$("<img />", {
    "src": 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYUxi.jpg?s=32&g=1',
    "class": "thumb-image "
  })
  .add("<a href='#'>Close</a>") //Injected this portion
  .appendTo(image_holder)
  .wrapAll("<div class='uimg_holder'></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image_holder"></div>
```